# How to read UnitPrice from invoice line in QBO API v3 .NET

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

The bizarre properties in the .NET SDK continue to baffle me. How do I read the UnitPrice from an invoice line?

If I do this:

```
sild = (SalesItemLineDetail)line.AnyIntuitObject;
ln = new QBInvoiceLine(); // My internal line item class
ln.Description = line.Description;
ln.ItemRef = new QBRef() { Id = sild.ItemRef.Value, Name = sild.ItemRef.name };
if (sild.QtySpecified)
    ln.Quantity = sild.Qty;
else
    ln.Quantity = 0;
if (sild.ItemElementName == ItemChoiceType.UnitPrice)
    ln.Rate = (decimal)sild.AnyIntuitObject;    // Exception thrown here
```

The last line throws an invalid cast exception, even though the debugger shows that the value is 20. I've tried other types but get the same exception no matter what I do. So I finally punted and am calculating the rate like so:

```
ln.Rate = line.Amount / ln.Quantity;
```

(With proper rounding and checking for divide by zero, of course)

While we're on the subject... I noticed that in many cases ItemElementName == ItemChoiceType.PriceLevelRef. What's up with that? As far as I know, QBO doesn't support price levels, and I certainly wasn't using a price level with this invoice or customer. In this case I was also able to get what I needed from the Amount property.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
SalesItemLineDetail a1 = (SalesItemLineDetail)invoice11.Line[0].AnyIntuitObject;
object unitprice = a1.AnyIntuitObject;
decimal quantity = a1.Qty;
```

PriceLevelRef as an 'entity' is not supported. This means CRUD operations are not supported on this entity. 
The service might however be returning readonly values in the transactions sometimes, but since this not mentioned in the docs, please consider it as unsupported.

Check that both request/response are in either json or xml format-
You can use the following code to set that-

```
ServiceContext context = new ServiceContext(appToken, realmId, intuitServiceType, reqvalidator);
context.IppConfiguration.Message.Request.SerializationFormat = Intuit.Ipp.Core.Configuration.SerializationFormat.Json;         
context.IppConfiguration.Message.Response.SerializationFormat = Intuit.Ipp.Core.Configuration.SerializationFormat.Json;
```

Also, in QBO UI, check if Company->sales settings has Track Quantity and Price/rate turned on.

Comment: Thanks but that still doesn't solve my cast problem. Using your code, I still have to do "myUnitPrice = (decimal)unitprice;" and that's where it throws the exception.

Comment: Please check if you have request/response format are both xml or both json. Check the edit above.